# How To Get Old & New value from BindingSource in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how to use `BindingSource` to get the old and new value from a GUI form. I'm Using `BindingSource` in my C# and now I want to fire `updateLog` SP.

So how do I know what field has been update, its new new value and its old value?

Comment: Didn't you mean `ItemsSource` ? (in XAML)

Comment: Can you show your code, there are some solutions to do so without `BindingSource`

Comment: if you want to log changes in another table, that would be so much easier to do in a trigger on the database. This wil also log any changes made by other software then your client

Comment: @GuidoG correct, you can put all your logic in the database ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to watch the [ListChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the BindingSource. The associated event handler takes a parameter, named [ListChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) that contains OldIndex and NewIndex properties that you may use